# Problema con focus de ion-input y ion-textarea en un modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Tengo un formulario con ion-textarea en un ion-modal  y al escribir se va el focus.
He buscado y no he podido dar con la solución.
¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Modificar Producto</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close">
        </ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let r of row | keyvalue">
        <ion-label position="stacked">{{r.key}}</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="row[r.key]" [disabled]="r.key == 'precio_lista' || r.key == 'precio_internet' || r.key == 'sku'"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-button (click)="alertConfirm(row)" slot="end" class="ion-margin-end">Guardar</ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resoler esto hay que agregar el siguiente pipe **trackBy: trackByFn**

```
<ion-content> 
    <ion-item *ngFor="let r of row | keyvalue; trackBy: trackByFn">
          <ion-label position="stacked" color="primary">{{r.key}}</ion-label>
          <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="row[r.key]" required = true [disabled]="r.key == 'sku' || r.key == 'start_date_active' || r.key == 'end_date_active' || r.key == 'fecha_actualizacion'|| r.key == 'usuario_actualizacion'"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

En el .TS

```
  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
```